# Two php forms. second form gets data from first. but refreshing second page shows error

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I am displaying list of Devices info from database. Each device will have a 'show warning' button. User can click 'show warning' and I am using hidden field (value from hidden field to identify) to display device warning messages. There is an accept button for each warning from database(a list of warnings with accept button for each). The user can  click accept button so that the status of the warning will change from not-accepted to accepted (and the page will refresh). Problem is on refresh, as it has no info from first page, php returns error.

```
//page-1.. under each category (like electrical, mechanical, more than one types of devices
//device can be identified by using ID


echo '<tr><th>Category Name</th>';
echo '<td >' . $row['category']. '</td></tr>';

echo '<tr><th>Device ID</th>';
echo '<td >' . $row['ID']. '</td></tr>';

//form section. 

echo "<form action = alarms_list_display.php method =post>";
echo '<tr>';

echo "<td >"." <input type=submit    name=acceptID value=ShowAlarm"."  </td>";
echo "<td >"." <input type=hidden  name=hiddenID  value =". $row["ID"]."  </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

```
//second page..    alarms_list_display.php

include ("DBconnect.php");
$conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );

if(isset($_POST ['acceptID']))
    {$deviceID = $_POST['hiddenID'];

    }
     else {$deviceID='';}


//above code is problematic. as it is available only when i submit the first page.
//when updating the second page (and refreshing), $deviceID is not available anymore. 



//listing all warnings related to that device when user clicked the 'ShowAlarm' button.

if ($conn->connect_error) {die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE ID='$deviceID' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//form with buttons to accept warning
//skipped table heading parts
//each warning will have a serialNumber. Using to accept the warning and update the database

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           echo "<form action = alarms_list_display_copy.php method =get>";


            echo "<td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Warning"]. "</td>";

            echo "<td>"." <input type=hidden  name=hidden value =" .$row["SerialNumber"]."  </td>";
            echo "<td>"." <input type=submit    name=accept value=AcceptAlarm id=button1 class = formclass"."  </td>";
            echo "</tr>";

           echo "</form>";
  } else { echo "0 results"; }



//code to update when clicking the AcceptAlarm button.

  if (isset($_GET['accept'])){
        $query= "SELECT WarningAccept FROM dataTable WHERE  SerialNumber= '$_GET[hidden]' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $updateQuery = " UPDATE dataTable SET WarningAccept=1 WHERE  SerialNumber= '$_GET[hidden]' ";
        mysqli_query($conn, $updateQuery);

     }
```

Possible to submit first page. it will display all the warning corresponding to the device. But when accepting the warning, page will refresh and the $deviceID is not anymore. so it won't display any warning messages after updating. how to change it??? any help

Comment: For your current issue please elaborate on `php returns error`. What is that error? For additional notes.... you should look at some recently written tutorial. You have a number of issues here. You are open to SQL injections. You don't need to `echo` every line. You don't need to concatenate each element. Your HTML attribute's values should be encapsulated in quotes.

Comment: Hi.. I am aware of all your comments. Thank you.  I will change everything once it gets worked. Here there is no particular error. but submitting the second page will return '0 results' as $deviceID is not there anymore

Comment: Your `input` fields are invalid. Maybe the browser is correcting them and not transmitting them on the send? `"<td >"." <input type=submit    name=acceptID value=ShowAlarm"."  </td>"` should be `'<td><input type="submit"    name="acceptID" value="ShowAlarm" /></td>'`

Answer (score 0):

Your `second page` only gets value once `<form action = alarms_list_display.php method =post>";` gets submitted that's why you are geting error when you refresh the second page because it loses the `$_POST` array then

**SOLUTION**

You can set action of `<form action = alarms_list_display.php method =post>"` to the same page and store values in sessions then redirect it to the second page and then you can use values from your sessions

Comment: Ohh ya... it should work.. I will try.. Thank you so much

Comment: Farroq. i was about to apply this technique. I am already using one session to store log in details (user details). Is it okay to use multiple sessions? is there any security risk?

Comment: I don't think that it's not safe. Sessions are stored in the server. It's okay to use multiple sessions at a time. But you have to make sure that you are using most recently updated sessions